# Stacktrace throws exception but couldn't find exception's line number in my class

Tags: android, exception, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

```
> 09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3062)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.widget.ExpandableListView.dispatchDraw(ExpandableListView.java:233)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7093)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2699)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6989)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:361)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1737)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6989)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:361)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6989)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:361)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1739)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1466)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6989)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:361)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1882)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1544)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1280)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1882)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
>     09-10 11:38:07.166: E/AndroidRuntime(11497):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get exception but there is no line number to point my class. So how can i find exception? Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Have you solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164

its showing you have error in line number 164 in HeaderViewListAdapter.java class.

Comment: as you can see, HeaderViewListAdapter is a android.widget class. not in the app, then

Answer (score 0):

What probably happens here is either one of these :

- you pass an array to an adapter, and modify it before it is displayed
- you override your adapter to return a getCount() value that doesn't match your array size

Comment: This is actually bug in HeaderViewListAdapter (part of framework), class which wraps provided adapter when `addHeaderView` or `addFooterView` was invoked on ListView

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point on application start, for example in onCreate(), and start in debugging mode. Though, the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` should give you some directions, for example, where in your code do you access the value of an `ArrayList` object?

Comment: When you run in debug mode you see how the applications runs through the code line by line, so you should be able to see the line where it trows the exception.

Answer (score -2):

**java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1**
It means your Array size is 1,
you try to get array[1] instead of array[0]

please send code.

Comment: It's not his code, it's Android, and he is looking to better trace the issue.